# VBA FileCopy: file not found issue

Tags: vba, file-copying

I am working on a project in VBA where I'm searching a directory for files of a certain date that also meet other criteria, and all of that is working fine. What I am stuck on, which should be a trivial issue, is that when I try to use FileCopy to copy the file to another folder, I keep getting a path/file access error. This confuses me because I am pulling the path directly from the FileItem I'm using to search for the criteria, I'm the person who created both the source and destination folders, and put the files in the source folder. Any thoughts?

```
Sub ListFilesInFolder()

    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim theString1 As String, theString2 As String
        theString1 = "ISA*00*"
        theString2 = "ISA|00|"
    Dim line As String, fileName As String
    Dim datestring As String
        'datestring = Format(FileItem.DateLastModified, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    Dim today As String
        today = Format(DateAdd("d", -2, Date), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    Dim destinationFolder As String
        destinationFolder = "C:\Users\kragan\Desktop\test\folder2"
    Dim file As TextStream
    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
        Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder
        Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\kragan\Desktop\test\folder1")
    Dim FileItem As Scripting.file

    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
    datestring = "10/18/2015"
        If (datestring = today) Then
            Do While (SourceFolder <> "")
                Set file = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileItem)
                counter = 0

                Do While Not file.AtEndOfLine And counter < 1
                    line = file.ReadLine

                    If InStr(1, line, theString1, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, line, theString2, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        fileName = "C:\Users\kragan\Desktop\test\folder1\" + FSO.GetBaseName(FileItem) + ".AETCLS"

    'The line where I get the error:
                        FileCopy fileName, destinationFolder

                        file.Close
                        counter = counter + 1
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop
            Loop
        End If
    Next FileItem
    MsgBox ("done")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify **destination folder + destination file name** (and not only destination folder).

So this will work:

```vb
FileCopy fileName, destinationFolder & "\" & FSO.GetBaseName(FileItem) & ".AETCLS"
```

You were probably assuming this will work like a file manager application, where giving destination folder is enough... :) But when programming, you need to specify destination path exactly as it is, i.e. including the file name.

One of my friends was getting similar error on creating directory `newdir1\newdir2\newdir3`. It was not working despite his best effort. But the solution was to create `newdir1`, then it became possible to specify `newdir1\newdir2`, then finally `newdir1\newdir2\newdir3`. Programming file operations does not do the job often seen in file managers, but everything must be specified in detail and performed in elementary steps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. What I discovered is that you have to have the full destination path, including the file name, even though it isn't changing. Solved!

Comment: It would be welcome if you could mark the most helpful answer as accepted by clicking the check mark on its left side. Thank you.